# how to make two inser svg elements side by side in a bigger div

Tags: html, svg

Hello all I am working on html and javascript.And I am going to ask a very basic question. I have written a simple code tried different thing.But unable to make it work my bad.
What I want to do is that I have a div which has two inner divs.Both inner divs has an svg element inside equal to the size of div.and I want both inner divs to be side by side.But my divs are not equal Ist div is big second is small in width.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div position:relative; width = "100%"; height = "400px" float:left>
  <div width = "1000px" height = "400px"; float:left>
    <svg width = "1000px" height = "400px"> 
    </svg>
  </div >
  <div width = "300px" height = "400px"float:left>
    <svg width = "300px" height = "400px"> 
    </svg>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this.
**Also should i write height and width with both div and svg or it fine to use with only one**

Comment: You may want to change the `svg`'s width/height to 100%.  That way they'll take up the space of the parent container.

Comment: thanks @SomeKittens but I am unable to align them side by side :(

Comment: Edited my answer below, see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `divs` to be equal in width, you'll need to set their `width` value to be equal.  There are two ways of doing this.  First, you could manually set the width:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div position:relative; width = "100%" height = "400px">
  <div width = "1000px" height = "400px" style="float:left">
    <svg width = "1000px" height = "400px"> 
    </svg>
  </div >
  <div width = "1000px" height = "400px" style="float:right">
    <svg width = "1000px" height = "400px"> 
    </svg>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, you could just use percentages:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div position:relative; width = "100%"; height = "400px">
  <div width = "50%" height = "400px" style="float:left">
    <svg width = "100%" height = "400px"> 
    </svg>
  </div >
  <div width = "50%" height = "400px" style="float:right">
    <svg width = "100%" height = "400px"> 
    </svg>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In both cases, if you want the divs to be side-by-side, one needs to be `float:right` and the other `float:left`.  There are other ways of accomplishing this but `floats` are simple.

Comment: Thank for your response but they are still appearing one above another no side by side

Comment: Did you change the floats?  Are you using IE?

Comment: The top-level div shouldn't float

Comment: I've just realized that you have a major syntax error.  The html needs to be `style="float:right;"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13420/discussion-between-somekittens-and-a-user)

Answer (score 0):

You can add float inside svg tag

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <div>
  <div>
    <svg width = "1000px" height = "400px" style="float:right"> 
    </svg>
  </div >
  <div>
    <svg width = "300px" height = "400px" style="float:right"> 
    </svg>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Read more here](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Using_SVG_with_HTML5_tutorial)